# How can I use purrr to limit rows where column element is not a list

Tags: r, purrr

I have a data.frame,df, where one of the columns has entries which are either a character or list

[image]

I would like to use the purrr package, or other means, to eliminate the second row

```
df <- structure(list(member_id = c("1715", "2186", "2187"), date_of_birth = list(
"1953-12-15T00:00:00", structure(list(`@xsi:nil` = "true", 
    `@xmlns:xsi` = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"), .Names = c("@xsi:nil", 
"@xmlns:xsi")), "1941-02-16T00:00:00")), .Names = c("member_id", 
"date_of_birth"), row.names = c(1L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

TIA

Comment: `df[sapply(df$date_of_birth, function(x) typeof(x)!="list"),]`?

Comment: with `library(tidyverse)` : `df %>% filter(map_lgl(date_of_birth, ~ !is.list(.)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to drop any row whose `date_of_birth` field is of type `list`, the following should be a decent solution:

```
df[sapply(df$date_of_birth, function(x) typeof(x)!="list"),]
```

Edit:

Imo's comment should shorten the above solution as follows:

```
df[!sapply(df$date_of_birth, is.list),]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There's also `is.list`. So you could do `df[!sapply(df$date_of_birth, is.list),]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R method using `lengths` and subsetting. Any element in the date_of_birth column that has more than one element is dropped

```
dfNew <- df[lengths(df$date_of_birth) < 2,]
```

which returns

```
dfNew
  member_id       date_of_birth
1      1715 1953-12-15T00:00:00
9      2187 1941-02-16T00:00:00
```

Note that `dfNew$date_of_birth` will still be of type list, which might cause problems down the line. You can fix this with `unlist`.

```
dfNew$date_of_birth <- unlist(dfNew$date_of_birth)
```